# Updating or creating undeclared column

Tags: oracle

I have an Oracle SQL file for creating tables and objects. The relevant part in regard to this question is as shown:

```
create type address_object as object (state char(2), zip char(10));
create table extaddr of address_object;
update extaddr set object_column.state = 'GA' where object_column = :addrref;
```

There is no object `object_column` in the whole SQL file but there are statements using the `object_column` like in the last SQL insertion statement above.

Where is `object_column` created or how do we `update` values to a derived object in Oracle?

Comment: That is invalid, there is no pseudo column named "object_column". Did you try running the above DDL and update statement and found it to work? It shouldn't.

Comment: That's about OCI (Oracle Call Interface). In code examples (here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A58617_01/server.804/a58234/app_exam.htm), search for OBJECT_COLUMN (there are 3 references) which (guess what?) contain *exact* UPDATE statement you posted. I don't know OCI but - if you're really interested in that, now you know what to search for.

Comment: @PaulW it cannot run. I was concerned if there could be a pseudo thing. There context is as @.Littlefoot has pointed but I dont understand for instance where object_column is coming from.

Comment: In those OCI sample programs (which are still listed [in the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/lnoci/oci-demo-programs.html#GUID-75E18629-0C54-4495-A747-AFB346034F26), and you can still get) that query is defined in `cdemo82.h` as `bndref` - which doesn't ever seem to be referred to. I don't believe that query would ever have worked, unless some *really* old version allowed if (e.g. Oracle 7); so it seems to be garbage they have never noticed and so never removed from the demos. (The code appears to have been written in 1996, and last updated in 2013...)

Answer (score 0):

> Where is `object_column` created

Given your statements and code you supplied, it isn't created anywhere.

There are [pseudo-columns](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Pseudocolumns.html#GUID-6C65C788-76AA-4A51-B011-51D53DD2521D) `object_id` and `object_value` but not `object_column`.

```sql
update extaddr set object_column.state = 'GA' where object_column = :addrref;
```

Appears to be an invalid statement as there is no `object_column` attribute of `address_object` and, therefore, no column with that name in `extaddr` and tring to update a non-existent column will fail.

> how do we update values to a derived object in Oracle?

The object table `extaddr` can be updated exactly like a normal table:

```sql
UPDATE extaddr
SET   state = 'CA'
WHERE zip = '95117';
```